# Flow header text background color

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow

I am new to Flows and have been trying to normalize several existing Flows across our org.  I have one screen flow where the screen header font has a different background than the header itself and I can't figure out how that happened, much less how to get rid of it!  I would be glad to make the whole flow screen background white, or make the background color of the header text grey like the rest. It just looks very unattractive in its current format. Any suggestions would be massively appreciated!

[image: example header font background color]

Comment: It looks like the existing flows are using customized aura component which show the current UI, if you find out that [aura component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens_replace_header.htm) , you would be able to change the whole header and its backgroudn as you want.

Comment: I will look for that, thank you Shivankur!